# formatting a string :%20s

Tags: java, string, formatting, string-formatting

Hi I'm new to java programming 
while trying to write some simple codes I saw this formatted string 
I know how it works but my question is about the integer we put between **%** and **s** ...
at first i thought it might be about the length of the blank field like if it is 5 we will see 5 space characters but i was wrong

if we put any integer smaller than 20 it wont work at all and when i put 20 the field length was 9 space characters...

i would appreciate if you could help me

Comment: did you read the documentation? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: Adding an [MCVE] would help explaining what you observe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%20s` means your String will be left-padded if its length is less than 20.

- If your String is `length` characters long with length<20, then it will add  `(20-length)` space characters to the left.
- If your String is more than 20 characters, then nothing is added (and the String is not truncated)

Examples:

```
System.out.println(":" + String.format("%20s", "HelloWorld") + ":");
:          HelloWorld:

System.out.println(":" + String.format("%20s", "Damn this is a long string") + ":");
:Damn this is a long string:
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an object called client with getId, getName, and getSurname methods (all strings):

```
System.out.format(" id:       %1$5s | \t" +
                  " First Name: %2$-12s | \t" +
                  " Last Name: %3$14s \n", client.getId(), client.getName(), client.getSurname());
```

Explanation:

%1

%2

%3

those are the number of the argument that follows

$5s     states 5 spaces and a string is spected

$-12s   states 12 spaces and the string will be shown to the left

$14s   states 14 spaces and the string will be shown to the right

Hope it helps!"

Answer (score -1):

When we format the string using

```
String.format("%*some_no* s", "*some_string*")
```

it will give *some_no* - *length of some_string* of spaces before printing the string.

> What this means is that your string will be padded with spaces until the length of the final string is equal to *some_no*

Check out https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format

Comment: @jhamon well, thanks for update. I added **almost**. And who downvoted my answer? I think, I answered correctly?